# Unable to bind an object as a value for Select component (Ant Design) in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have an issue while selecting the object as value for Select component ([Ant Design](https://ant.design/components/select)).

This is what I'm trying to do

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
//Other imports

export const NewInvoice = () => {
    const [selectedCustomer, setSelectedCustomer] = useState(null);
    const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);
    
    // other fields


    useEffect(() => {
        if (checkAuthentication(getToken())) {
            fetchCustomers().then((data) => {
                setCustomers(data);
            });
        }
        //eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    const customerNameHelper = (customer) => {
        return `${customer?.customerNumber ?? ""} - ${customer?.name ?? "Unkown"}, ${customer?.addressDto?.city ?? "Unknown"}`;
    };

    const getCustomerAsOptions = (customers) => {
        return customers.map((item) => ({
            label: customerNameHelper(item),
            value: item, // item = {id, name, customerNumber, ...}
        }));
    };
    
    return (
        // other components
        {customers.length > 0 && (
            <Select
                style={{
                    width: 380,
                }}
                className="customerSelectionDropdown"
                value={customerNameHelper(selectedCustomer)}
                onChange={(value) => {
                    setSelectedCustomer(value);
                }}
                placeholder="Select Customer"
                options={getCustomerAsOptions(customers)}
                dropdownStyle={dropDownStyles}
                showSearch
                allowClear
            />
        )}
    );
};
```

Whenever I try to select the option it is saying **Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, customerNumber, email, phone, pendingAmount, createdDate, addressDto, totalPurchaseAmount}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

Is there any solution to address this issue? Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending an `object` to property `value` in `getCustomerAsOptions`

[`CODESANDBOX`](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/fancy-sea-5k8jll?file=/src/App.js:27,14)

```
  const getCustomerAsOptions = (customers) => {
    return customers.map((item) => ({
      label: customerNameHelper(item),

      // CHANGE
      value: item.customerNumber, // item = {id, name, customerNumber, ...}
    }));
  };
```

Type of the `Option` in `antd` is `string | number | null`:

```
    label: React.ReactNode;
    value?: string | number | null;
```

You have to pass only `string` | `number` | `null` and you are passing an object which throws error.

> IMO: You should pass `unique` identifier so that on selecting a value from dropdown you can identify which element has been clicked. On click of an option it will return same `value` to you in `onChange` callback

```
  onChange={(value) => {
    setSelectedCustomer(value);
  }}
```

---

`MODIFICATION`: If you want to tract the object then you can create state and set it in `onChange` callback as:

```
onChange={(value) => {
  const selectedCust = customers.find(
    (o) => o.customerNumber === value,
  );
  if (selectedCust) setSelectedCustomer(selectedCust);
}}
```

---

`MODIDFICATION 2`: If you want to set the selected object then you can use second args to `onChange` as:

```
onChange={(value, selectedCust) => {
  setSelectedCustomer(selectedCust);
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But as per my requirement I need to hold the selected customer object to the state. Upon selecting the customer, other fields will be filled with the customer data.

Comment: @NagarajuKasarla If you want to hold selected customer object then you can can create a state and set it on selecting in `onChange`

Comment: Sure, After selecting a customer as an object from dropdown in onChangeHandler `selectedCustomer` field will be set to selected object. 
Like`onChange((value) => setSelectedCustomer(value)`. This selected customer information is used in some other places of the component. 

For example `<Input id="discountField" value={selectedCustomer.discuount}>` .

Comment: @NagarajuKasarla Check the modification and verify it on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/fancy-sea-5k8jll?file=/src/App.js:54,11-59,13)

Comment: I appreciate for your patience. Similar solution I found in chatGPT but for my case I have around 100000 customers so in worst case it take O(N) time complexity so it take couple of seconds to set the state. I need that in log(n) or O(1). Currently, we are able to hold `string | number` in value field, why not we can hold the entire object ?

Comment: @NagarajuKasarla Modification 2 added. You can get selected value form `second` argument to `onChange` function

Comment: It should cater all of your requirements

Comment: Thanks for your patience. It feels great to discuss with you

Comment: Glad you got your solution

Answer (score 0):

Based on the modification of @DecPK now I'm able hold the entire option. So just adding an extra field I can hold the object.

```
const getCustomerAsOptions = (customers) => {
    return customers.map((item) => ({
        value: item.customerNumber,
        label: customerNameHelper(item),
        customValue: item
    }));
};
```

Select component onChange handler

```
value={customerNameHelper(customer)}
onChange={(value, selectedCustomer) => {
    if (selectedCustomer && selectedCustomer.customValue) 
        setCustomer(selectedCustomer.customValue);
        console.log(customer);
    }
}
```